# displaying random no in the applet

Tags: java, applet

i want to display random no in the applet as long as the applet is running but its not displaying . kindly guide whats wring with the code

```
package javaapplication1;
 import java.util.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class set extends Applet implements Runnable {
    private DateFormat formatter = null;
    private Thread t = null;

    public void init() {

        int n = (int)(10.0 * Math.random()) + 1;
       System.out.print(n);
        t = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        t = null;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        //
        // Show the current time on the browser status bar
        //
        this.showStatus(formatter.format(now));
    }

    public void run() {
        int delay = 1000;
        try {
            while (t == Thread.currentThread()) {
                //
                // Repaint the applet every on second
                //
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and its floating with the following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
4Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javaapplication1.set.paint(set.java:39)
        at java.awt.Container.update(Container.java:1801)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:239)
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:216)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to display it, and which bit of your code do you think will be achieving this?

At the moment I can see you create a random number and then call `System.out.println` with that number.  This will print the number out *to the console*, but it will not display it in your applet.

You'll need to put some logic in the `paint(Graphics g)` method to display this number - for example, calling [g.drawString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29).  However there are a multitude of ways that you could possibly output text, depending on how you want it to loko at what you have already, such that it's not plausible to give a single correct, or more specific, answer to this question.

You should take another look at an applet tutorial that goes over how you control the output, and perhaps post back with more *specific* questions based on the outcome of that.

Comment: @ Andrzej Doyle Thank you but even on the console mode there is nothing and its floating exception which i have updated in the question

Comment: @umar OK, thanks for the feedback - but that exception was **essential** information for the problem you were having.  If you include all the relevant output/behaviour when you ask questions in future, you'll get more accurate responses more quickly, and everyone wins.

Answer (score 2):

This should not have been difficult. A `NullPointerException` occurs when you try to do an operation on a `null`.

You have a `NullPointerException` in your *own* code (as opposed to code in a library). All you have to do is to go to that line and see what all possibly can be `null`.

In the line

```
this.showStatus(formatter.format(now));
```

`formatter` is (most likely) `null`. This is the reason for the `NullPointerException`.

<sub><sub>I think stackoverflow is making people infinitely lazy.</sub></sub>

Comment: +1 since this is the real problem.  The `formatter` is never assigned anywhere so *must* be null.  (On a side note, this is yet another situation where immutability would have sidestepped the "is it set or not" question altogether).  (Oh, and +1 again for the tiny text with the big point.)